# Regex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose we don't know how many slashes we could get in a string but we do not want any extra slashes. So if we get this string '/hello/world///////how/are/you//////////////' we should transform it to the form of '/hello/world/how/are/you/'. How to do it with the help of regular expressions in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'/hello/world///////how/are/you//////////////'.replace(/\/{2,}/g, '/');
```

This *might* be an incy wincy bit faster than mkoryak's suggestion, for it will only replace where necessary – i.e., where there's multiple instances of `/`. I'm sure someone with a better understanding of the nuts and bolts of the JavaScript regular expression engine can weigh in on this one.

**UPDATE**: I have now profiled mine and mkoryak's solutions using the above string but duplicated hundreds of times, and I can confirm that my solution consistently worked out several milliseconds faster.

Comment: Myself I tried doing the way you suggested ({2,}), but without the g letter. So it didn't work properly (replaced only once).

Answer (score 3):

```
"/hello/world///////how/are/you//////////////".replace(/\/+/g, "/")
```

Comment: By the way, what does that g letter mean?

Comment: global replace, so basically it makes it a replaceAll which is what you want

Comment: Just expanding on the `g`: if it wasn't there, it would replace the first instance of `/` and then give up. The `g` flag effectively means, "keep on going until you've got them all."

Answer (score 0):

### Edited: mkoryak's answer below is way better. Leaving this in case the info it contains is useful for someone else.

You could capture each word + slash group and look ahead (but don't capture) for one or more extra slash.  Like...

```
(\w+\/)(?:\/)*(\w+\/)(?:\/)*
```

First () captures one or more of any word character followed by a slash, second () looks for a slash but doesn't capture, * means find 0 or more of the proceeding token.  Etc.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I want to make a regex for string which matches from point A till point B

text= "testtttExecuted 'show bootvar' on \n10.238.196.66. kjdkhfkh Executed tsttt\n fhgkhkh"

Output should be

testtttExecuted 'show bootvar' on \n10.238.196.66. kjdkhfkh

```html
I want to make a regex for string which matches from point A till point B

text= "testtttExecuted 'show bootvar' on \n10.238.196.66. kjdkhfkh Executed tsttt\n fhgkhkh"


Output should be

testttt<font color='red'>Executed 'show bootvar' on \n</font>10.238.196.66. kjdkhfkh <font color='red'>Executed tsttt\n</font> fhgkhkh
```